# Index Notation, Multiplying a 3rd order tensor with a 2nd order tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, index-notation

I have a newbie question regarding the equality $$W_{ik}=-\omega_l\varepsilon_{ikl},$$

where $\varepsilon_{lik}$ is the Levi-Civita permutation symbol. Now, I want to solve for $\omega_l$ and my question is: Are both of the following two manipulations allowed?

$$(1):-\varepsilon_{ikl}W_{ik}=\omega_l\varepsilon_{ikl}\varepsilon_{ikl}=6\omega_l$$
$$(2):-\varepsilon_{ikq}W_{ik}=\omega_l\varepsilon_{ikl}\varepsilon_{ikq}=2\delta_{lq}\omega_l=2\omega_q$$

In the book i'm using, they chose (2) but I can't find any reason as to why (1) would not be valid, is it simply a matter of taste?

Best regards
Bengt

Comment: (1) is not valid because $l$ is being used. You only have free indices $i,k$.

Comment: So a dummy index can only appear twice in a factor? I guess in my case, having the indice l appear three times makes the r.h.s ambigous?

Comment: Exactly. Indices must appear alone (like $i,k$) or by pairs (like $l$ in your untagged equation).

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.